# ProcessBuilder process not providing real time output

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm running ProcessBuilder in a java program using eclipse IDE and Ubuntu 20.04. Specifically for bluetooth LE commands. For commands like "hciconfig" the process completes and I can print the output to the console or a textarea (JFX). Other commands like hcidump run continuously until manually terminated. For these commands I'm unable to print the intermediate output while the process is running. I've tried both the apache.commons CommandLine and the java ProcessBuilder methods probably 6 ways to sundown each. This should be a fairly straightforward task but so far no luck. Here is the java code:

```
Process pb = new ProcessBuilder()
        .command("hcidump", "-i", "hci0")
        .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
        .start();

System.out.println(pb.getOutputStream().toString());
```

The printed output stream appears to be an address:
java.lang.ProcessImpl$ProcessPipeOutputStream@b06aa6f

How do I access the process output while the process is still running?

Comment: You must read from the output stream,  now you are just calling toString(). What gets printed is not an adress, and is not the output from the command.

Comment: Open XTerm, type hcidump and hit enter. This "process" scans for other local BLE devices. If one is found then a report is displayed in the terminal while the process continues to scan until the user types cntl C. It is this "real-time" output that I want to duplicate in java/JFX. The methods suggested so far only seem to function after the process ends and then only if it ends naturally on it's own. I'm nearly convinced that ProcessBuilder doesn't allow real-time transfer of process output. Maybe apache commons CommandLine will transfer real-time...

Comment: @user12026064 Do you get "immediately" output when you use the "ping" command instead like in `.command("ping", "-c", "4", "127.0.0.1")`?

Comment: Using the debug mode I see that once the sub-process .start() is executed the parent process waits until the sub=process ends. i.e. no subsequent code is executed. Well that's not a surprise. Others have claimed to solve this problem by creating another thread that runs in the background. Guess I'll work on that...

Comment: Progman, yes, after a process terminates normally I get the appropriate output. The hcidump command does not normally terminate but runs until it's manually terminated. That is the whole problem. Thanks to all who have helped.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem and saw your question while searching for a solution. I could solve it eventually by using a buffered reader, writer, two threads as subclasses and a completable future.

Right after creating the process I create these.

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder(/*Your command*/);

    try {
        setActiveProcess(pb.start());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    Thread wait = new Thread(new ProcessWait());
    Thread read = new Thread(new AsyncRead());
    read.start();
    wait.start();
```

The set activeProcess method simply creates the reader and writer instances as follows

```
private void setActiveProcess(Process p) {
    if (p == null) {
        activeProcess = null;
        writer = null;
        reader = null;
        readFinished = null;
    }
    else {
        activeProcess = p;
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(activeProcess.getOutputStream()));
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        readFinished = new CompletableFuture<Boolean>();
    }
}
```

Then the read thread actively waits for process output

```
private class AsyncRead implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int s;
        try {
            while (reader != null && ((s = reader.read()) != -1)) {
                System.out.print((char)s);
            }
            if (readFinished != null) {
                readFinished.complete(true);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and wait thread actively waits for process to finish without blocking

```
 private class ProcessWait implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int status = -1;
        try {
            status = activeProcess.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (status != 0) {
            System.err.println("Process failed");
            return;
        }
        try {
            Boolean finished = readFinished.get();
            if (finished) {
                setActiveProcess(null);
                removeFiles();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

The readFinished variable ensures that the process is not set to null before the reading is not over. I used it for compiling and running C++ programs you can see the whole code in : https://github.com/Onnrr/ProcessBuilderCppCompile